# A better way to implement margins in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell, margin

Apple has deprecated margins in table views, since iOS7, but designers still seem to want margins. What’s the best way t implement margins in iOS 7 and above? The old “group” table view style that included margins in iOS 6 no longer indents the left and right edges.

I have a`UITableView` subclass, in which i’m using the following method to programmatically add margins to the edge of all subviews, except the`backgroundView` (such as cells, section header etc):

**Code:**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if (subview != self.backgroundView && subview.frame.origin.x == 0.0 && subview.frame.size.width == self.frame.size.width) {
            subview.frame = CGRectInset(subview.frame, 10.0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

During runtime, it all seems to work as desired. The cells resize according to the margin offset and the subviews of those cells adjust correctly.

However, in the storyboard, using`IBDesignable`, the cells adjust correctly but the cells’ subviews do not seem to resize within the cell’s calculated size

Is there a better way to implement margins in a`UITableView`?

Thanks c:

Comment: Do you mean left indents for each cell?

Comment: I mean the left and right edge of all cells, section headers, footers, etc. I effectively want to put a margin (or inset) around the entire contents of the tableView, except the background view, just like iOS 6 did for the "group style". My layoutSubviews code above does the job at run time but has a quirk with IBDesignable in the storyboard. So, I wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: I believe `UITableViewCells` can have `contentInsets` but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

**UIEdgeInsets** is used to implement margins around the tableview that looks like grouped tableview. You may try below solutions and check it.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];//iOS7
    }

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

   if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
   }
}
```

//OR

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    // Force your tableview margins (this may be a bad idea)
    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [self.tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

For iOS 8 use

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)layoutMargins {
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Apple switched to layout margins in iOS 8.  The advantage of adding constraints to margins instead of edges, is that your margin is now adaptive, and will adjust itself, based on the screen's traits.

After I transitioned to constraining to margins (instead of edges), I really appreciated how it simplified layout, and eliminating having to adjust constraints myself.  It does the work for me, and it looks pleasing.